# Can't get rpart to run

Tags: r, statistics, version, rpart

I'm trying to re-run some code that worked well previously.  When I enter my code, I get this error:
`could not find function rpart`

However, when I run the `find.package` function, I have it:
`[1] "C:/Users/maltm/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rpart"`

I also get this warning:

```
package ‘rpart’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

It also tells me I need the `stats` package, which the `find.package` function tells me I have.  Here's the error message for that:

```
Error: package ‘stats’ could not be loaded`
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rpart’ was built under R version 4.0.5 
Warning: namespace ‘stats’ is not available and has been replaced
by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘<unknown>’
```

I just reinstalled R and have the latest version (`2021.09.0,Build 351`; check for updates tells me I have the latest version), so am not sure what to do here. Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what's happening since these error messages seem to contradict one another. When you start a new R session, what is the exact sequence of commands you run and output you get? Also 2021.09.0 is a version number for RStudio, not R. RStudio is just an editor. R is installed separately and has a different version numbering system. You can install R from https://cloud.r-project.org/

Comment: I updated to the latest version of R. (Tools/Global Options:  [64-bit] C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-40~1.2. )  When I restarted, I get the following error: Loading required package: stats
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘stats’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rpart’ was built under R version 4.0.5

Comment: The stats package is part of the base R installation. What has probably happened is that the update has transitioned from R 4.0.x to R.1.x and that the pointer to the user library has changed and that you are finding an old installation. When R versions change you typically need to create a new library directory and somehow repopulate that directory with updated packages. There are many SO questions and answers on how to do this. You can demonstrate this by looking at the output of `.libPaths()` and noting that it is probably looks something like `"C:/Users/maltm/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/"`